# npm is really slow while installing/updating packages from private git repositories

Tags: node.js, git, npm, installation, updates

I use a lot of private node packages (stored on my personal github repositories) in my projects:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "my-package": "github:username/my-package#master"
  ...
}
```

my issues is that, when updating a project or when running `npm install`, the process takes so long (~ 2 mins), while it's stuck doing something like:

```
reify:my-package: timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
```

Is there anything I can do to speed up the processes when using private repos?

Thanks

Comment: npm install has been awfully slow since npm 7, it can get stuck for minutes in this `reify` not just with private repos but public packages too. although private repos can be notoriously slower.

Comment: Have you tried the options listed on this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524903/why-is-npm-install-really-slow

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a problem with Private repositories or GitHub, NPM itself has been very slow recently. You might want to go with a faster alternative like `yarn`, It's much faster and can save a ton of time.

## Installation of Yarn

To install Yarn you just have to run `npm install yarn -g`. That will install yarn globally.

## Commands of Yarn

This cheat sheet of Yarn alternatives to NPM commands can help - https://shift.infinite.red/npm-vs-yarn-cheat-sheet-8755b092e5cc

Hope it helped :)